# Having trouble with parsing specific data from log file

Tags: python, parsing, logfile

I have an assignment in which the main task is to report suspicious activities within a log file. There are several other problems I have to address, but the one that I want to focus on the most is "suspicious activities" (if I can get a grasp on this then more than likely I'll have a lightbulb to help guide me on the rest). The way this is supposed to be achieved is to keep up a count for whenever a user logins between 12:00 am to 5:00 am. Once a user has been marked for being suspicious, the users' name, their email, and the domain name should be present as output information.

I have never worked with log files before and this is my first dealing with one using Python 3 (specifically PyCharm). So far it has proven challenging because I don't know where exactly to start this assignment. I originally planned to use regular expressions to match specific text in the log file and dictionaries for keys, but I wasn't sure if this was the correct frame of mind in tackling this assignment.

Here is the sample log: [Sample Behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oc7BL.png)

And here is a piece of the user log file
[userlog.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ll3d.png)

I apologize if my post comes off as a bit confusing, this is the very first time I have used Stack overflow. My goal is to gather thoughts and ideas of how I should tackle this assignment one step at a time. Thanks for any ideas or thoughts as well. Edit: below is a piece of the user log file pasted.

2020-05-23 00:44:42             login           mailserver.local                melaina.gabeline@yahoo.com.mx
2020-05-15 10:54:11             logout          mailserver.local                sevan.stephco@miho-nakayama.com
2020-05-07 11:25:24             login           myworkstation.local             breena.benassi@gmx.net
2020-05-14 16:31:34             logout          webserver.local                 arti.karshner@mail2perry.com
2020-05-12 17:02:10             login           mailserver.local                queen.ham@quiklinks.com
2020-05-30 23:01:30             logout          mailserver.local                maryelizabeth.stassen@freesurf.fr
2020-05-11 15:04:32             logout          myworkstation.local             lupe.gave@freesurf.fr
2020-05-26 13:51:35             logout          mailserver.local                tarrin.evanoff@blacksburg.net
2020-05-15 02:21:39             logout          mailserver.local                maryelizabeth.stassen@freesurf.fr
2020-05-05 14:16:13             login           mailserver.local                aprilmarie.ulatowski@freesurf.fr
2020-05-21 03:53:37             login           mailserver.local                tarrin.naysmith@mail2champaign.com
2020-05-05 06:17:09             login           webserver.local                 melaina.gabeline@yahoo.com.mx
2020-05-24 18:24:49             logout          myworkstation.local             kira.pay@mail2zambia.com

Comment: Please paste the data from the sample and user log so I can test. Which file should be read for the assignment?

Comment: @Mike67 sorry for the late reply. I'm not sure what you mean by pasting the data from the sample and user log, still kinda new here so I wasn't sure if I was able to add or link text files (hence the little snippets of the sample behavior and userlog). The more important file for this assignment is the userlog.log one. Edit: here is a link for the logfile https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gzQBT0J8ZY5QfZjW8OEdCSEORbg7zHbu/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Add the text from your userlog screen capture to your question so I can copy\paste to a script.

Comment: @Mike67 I edited my post to include the same screen capture text. Does that help in any way by chance?

Answer (score 0):

To read the log, use `readlines` to get all the file lines, For each line, use `split` to divide the line into columns. Use `datetime` to compare times.

To get list of users still logged in, add the user to a list at login, then remove the user at logout. At the end, use the remaining entries for the 'still logged in' list.

Try this code:

```
ss = '''
2020-05-23 00:44:42 login mailserver.local melaina.gabeline@yahoo.com.mx
2020-05-15 10:54:11 logout mailserver.local sevan.stephco@miho-nakayama.com
2020-05-07 11:25:24 login myworkstation.local breena.benassi@gmx.net
2020-05-14 16:31:34 logout webserver.local arti.karshner@mail2perry.com
2020-05-12 17:02:10 login mailserver.local queen.ham@quiklinks.com
2020-05-30 23:01:30 logout mailserver.local maryelizabeth.stassen@freesurf.fr
2020-05-11 15:04:32 logout myworkstation.local lupe.gave@freesurf.fr
2020-05-26 13:51:35 logout mailserver.local tarrin.evanoff@blacksburg.net
2020-05-15 02:21:39 logout mailserver.local maryelizabeth.stassen@freesurf.fr
2020-05-05 14:16:13 login mailserver.local aprilmarie.ulatowski@freesurf.fr
2020-05-21 03:53:37 login mailserver.local tarrin.naysmith@mail2champaign.com
2020-05-05 06:17:09 login webserver.local melaina.gabeline@yahoo.com.mx
2020-05-24 18:24:49 logout myworkstation.local kira.pay@mail2zambia.com
'''.strip()

with open('userlog.log','w') as f: f.write(ss)  # write log file

#############################

import datetime

loggedin = set()  # users still logged in
allusers = set()  # all users

FiveAM = datetime.datetime.strptime('05:00:00', '%H:%M:%S')

with open('userlog.log') as f:
   lines = f.readlines()
   for ln in lines:
      cols = ln.split()  # split at spaces, date is col 0, time is col 1
      dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(' '.join(cols[:2]), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')  # date\time
      tm = datetime.datetime.strptime(cols[1], '%H:%M:%S')  # time
      print(cols)
      allusers.add(cols[4])
      if cols[2] == 'login' and tm < FiveAM:
          print('>>> Suspicious! ' + cols[4] + ' is a spy!')
      if cols[2] == 'login':
          loggedin.add(cols[4])  # email, add to login list
      else: # logout
          if cols[4] in loggedin: loggedin.remove(cols[4])  # remove from login list
          
print('\n-- Users logged in -- \n', '\n'.join(loggedin), sep='')  # users still logged in

print('\n-- Users logged out -- \n', '\n'.join(allusers-loggedin), sep='')  # users not still logged in
```

Output

```
['2020-05-23', '00:44:42', 'login', 'mailserver.local', 'melaina.gabeline@yahoo.com.mx']
>>> Suspicious! melaina.gabeline@yahoo.com.mx is a spy!
['2020-05-15', '10:54:11', 'logout', 'mailserver.local', 'sevan.stephco@miho-nakayama.com']
['2020-05-07', '11:25:24', 'login', 'myworkstation.local', 'breena.benassi@gmx.net']
['2020-05-14', '16:31:34', 'logout', 'webserver.local', 'arti.karshner@mail2perry.com']
['2020-05-12', '17:02:10', 'login', 'mailserver.local', 'queen.ham@quiklinks.com']
['2020-05-30', '23:01:30', 'logout', 'mailserver.local', 'maryelizabeth.stassen@freesurf.fr']
['2020-05-11', '15:04:32', 'logout', 'myworkstation.local', 'lupe.gave@freesurf.fr']
['2020-05-26', '13:51:35', 'logout', 'mailserver.local', 'tarrin.evanoff@blacksburg.net']
['2020-05-15', '02:21:39', 'logout', 'mailserver.local', 'maryelizabeth.stassen@freesurf.fr']
['2020-05-05', '14:16:13', 'login', 'mailserver.local', 'aprilmarie.ulatowski@freesurf.fr']
['2020-05-21', '03:53:37', 'login', 'mailserver.local', 'tarrin.naysmith@mail2champaign.com']
>>> Suspicious! tarrin.naysmith@mail2champaign.com is a spy!
['2020-05-05', '06:17:09', 'login', 'webserver.local', 'melaina.gabeline@yahoo.com.mx']
['2020-05-24', '18:24:49', 'logout', 'myworkstation.local', 'kira.pay@mail2zambia.com']

-- Users logged in --
aprilmarie.ulatowski@freesurf.fr
melaina.gabeline@yahoo.com.mx
queen.ham@quiklinks.com
breena.benassi@gmx.net
tarrin.naysmith@mail2champaign.com

-- Users logged out --
maryelizabeth.stassen@freesurf.fr
lupe.gave@freesurf.fr
sevan.stephco@miho-nakayama.com
arti.karshner@mail2perry.com
tarrin.evanoff@blacksburg.net
kira.pay@mail2zambia.com
```

Comment: Hey Mike, quick question. If I wanted to delete lines that weren't suspicious, would it make sense to delete them based on index value? I ask this because each line does have a fixed index value, but that would also mean deleting over 300+ lines manually on the official userlog.

Comment: I would write the suspicious entries to another file for analysis and leave the original log file unchanged.

Comment: Hey @Mike67, I wondered if it was ok to ask one last question. I was able to write out the suspicious users to another file with no issues (thanks for the tip). But my question now is what if I need to report users who didn't log out on the user log? For example, one user only logged in 3 times and never logged out. Now, I began creating a dictionary with column[4] (emails) being the key and columns[2] (the login activity) as the value but python only printed out one email. I'm not too sure how to move forward on this one.

Comment: Gotcha, that's pretty much the same idea I was going for, thanks fam!

Comment: quick thing, I got curious and tried to do the opposite of users who logged in using the same set function in a different variable called logged out = set (), but I get the same output results as seen with logged in = set (). Would it be a better idea to store the user log in a dictionary for this kind of thing?

Comment: 'logged out' is just 'all users' - 'logged in'. Answer updated.

Comment: ooooh I gotcha. I see where I messed up now. I assumed that if you just made a separate set function using the same method that it would yield the opposite results. Didn't know you could just subtract the contents lol.